# Global Error Catcher

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In my project I want to log all the errors happen in the application in a database table. I catch almost all errors using try catch blocks, but I cannot catch the global errors like 4xx and 5xx.

There are cases that the application does not redirect to the Exception Handler defined in the Configure method of the Startup.cs like when I type a url which does not exist.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

Is there a way to catch all the unhandled errors occurred in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own Exception filter, which implements [`IExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iexceptionfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.0) e.g.:

```cs
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    ILogger<GlobalExceptionFilter> logger = null;

    public GlobalExceptionFilter(ILogger<GlobalExceptionFilter> exceptionLogger)
    {
        logger = exceptionLogger;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // log the exception
        logger.LogError(0, context.Exception.GetBaseException(), "Exception occurred.");
    }
}
```

You can then add this filter in your `ConfigureServices` method as follows:

```cs
services.AddMvc(o => { o.Filters.Add<GlobalExceptionFilter>(); });
```

This will catch any unhanded exceptions that occur as the result of a request. For 404s you can add the following to your `Configure` method:

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

You can then log the status code in your `ErrorController`.

For further information see [Introduction to Error Handling in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I have only one problem. In my routing I include the current language and I do not know how to include it in the             `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/en-US/error/{0}");`. Right now I use the 'en-US' but I want to use the lang routing value so that the system will use the current language.

Comment: I had a quick look but I'm not sure how to handle that either. Sorry, might need to create another question.

Comment: It is ok. I will ask a new question for this problem.

Comment: Since the OP is pretty unspecific, it should be noted, that this will only catch results which happen during a **request**. It won't catch exceptions outside of a request, i.e. caused by processes running in background (like schedule such as Hangfire etc.) (not, that running background tasks is a good idea in ASP.NET Core ;))