# Global exception filter does not trigger on exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to ASP.NET and C#. I am working with a ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC app.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   (services, Configuration)
   .RegisterMvc();
}
```

**RegisterMvc method**

```
public static (IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) RegisterMvc(this (IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) aspnet)
{
    var (services, configuration) = aspnet;

    services
        .AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
        });

    return aspnet;
}
```

**GlobalExceptionFilter**

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    var exception = context.Exception;
    Log.LogError(LogDescription, exception.Message, exception);
}
```

When an exception occurs, the execution flow needs to go into the OnException method but that is not happening. Ideas, anyone?

**Update**

This code works just fine, but I need this filter to trigger even when I catch the exception.

Comment: What exceptions (thrown when) are not going to that filter?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579037/6417765

Comment: Above code works correctly when you throw exception in Controller. Where did it not work for you?

Comment: Its not working when I catch an exception. @Edward

Comment: Where did the exception happen? Is there any reproducable project? Do you mean you use `try catch` to catch the exception, and you want this block code run into `OnException` again?`ExceptionFilter` only works for uncatched exception.

Comment: @Edward Gotcha. Is there another filter I can use for the exceptions I catch?

Comment: Why? Is there any specific reason for this requirement?

Comment: @Edward Yeah, I am calling a third party library and some of the exceptions returned by them are really cryptic. So, I want to log exceptions I catch as well so I have enough information to troubleshoot if those exceptions occur in production.

Comment: You may consider remove `try catch block` and let `ExceptionFilter` to capture these exception, or use `Log.LogError` in `try catch block`.